# List files that are in directory1 but NOT in directory2 and vice versa?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hey, I started bash shell scripting and I'm trying to make a script for an assignment that when you enter two directories, it will check if they exist and display according error message and if both directories DO exist, it will list the differences between the current directories.

```
$ cd dir-1
$ myshellscript . dir-2 (comparing . aka dir-1 against dir-2)
```

Output:

```
Files that are in . but not in dir-2
-rw------- 1 ddddd users   1 2011-03-1 01:26 123123123

Files that are in dir-2 but not in .
-rw------- 1 ddddd users   1 2011-03-1 01:26 zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

What I have so far that does not seem to detect whether a directory exists nor list differences:

```
dir-1=$1
dir-2=$2

if [ $# > 2  ]
   then
      echo "Usage: compdir dir-name1 dir-name 2"
      exit 1
   elif [ $# < 2 ]
      then
         echo "Usage: comdir dir-name1 dir-name 2"
   elif [ ! -d "$@" ]
      then
         echo "/$@ is not a valid existing directory"
   else
      exit 0
fi

echo $dir-1
echo $dir-2
```

List of commands I have to work with, otherwise I would have used `comm -32 <(ls -la dir-1)` `<(ls -la dir-2)`

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20930447/index.html
```

Comment: Yeah there are tons of better solutions but oh well =\

Answer (score 34, accepted):

a bit crude - but the easiest way I always use is (can play with the diff params, I typically use different grep

```
diff -rcw DIR1 DIR2| grep ^Only
```

then you can sort and format as you like

Revised to format (less efficient as we are running diff twice here ... easily solved)

```
echo files only in $dir1
LST=$(diff ${dir1} ${dir2}| grep "^Only in ${dir1}"| sed 's@^.*: @@')
(cd ${dir1}; ls -l ${LST})

echo files only in $dir2
LST=$(diff ${dir1} ${dir2}| grep "^Only in ${dir2}"| sed 's@^.*: @@')
(cd ${dir2}; ls -l ${LST})
```

Expanding on the sed expression above:
  s=search and replace
  the three '@' are separating the expressions (this is TRADITIONALLY done with '/')
  ^ matches the beginning of a line (forces the rest not to match elsewhere)
  . means any character
  * means the previous expression (.==match any char) 0-N times
  ": " is what I matched on from the diff output "Only in X: "

Look Mommy, no hands - now without 'sed' its beginning to be less and less crude

```
XIFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n\r'
for DIFFLINE in $(diff ${dir1} ${dir2}|grep ^Only); do
  case "${DIFFLINE}" in
   "Only in ${dir1}"*)  
    LST1="${LST1} ${DIFFLINE#*:}"
    ;;
   "Only in ${dir2}"*)  
    LST2+="${DIFFLINE#*:}"
    ;;
  esac
done
IFS="${XIFS}"

echo files only in $dir1
(cd ${dir1}; ls -l ${LST1})

echo files only in $dir2
(cd ${dir2}; ls -l ${LST2})
```

You will probably want to know about IFS ... it needs some reading in the bash manual, but its basically the field separator characters ... by default they include spaces and I don't want the loop to be fed with fractions of lines, just complete lines - so for the duration of the loop I override the default IFS to just newlines and carriage returns.

BTW maybe your professor is reading stackoverflow, maybe next you wont be allowed to use semicolons ;-) ...  (back to 'man bash' ... BTW if you do 'man bash' do it in emacs, makes much easier to read IMO)

Comment: How do I format that? This is closer to what I need. `diff dir1 dir2 | grep a` worked perfectly to output files in a that are not in b and vice versa. Now I don't how to style it so that it looks like output when you use the command `ls -la`, if you could answer that I'd be golden :)

Comment: I don't know what your formatting requirements are ... you didn't provide a sample output ... what I listed shows you which files exist in one but not the other dir

Comment: The output is in the OP of this thread, i need the output to say instead of just a simple statement of files that are in a and not in b, it need to be in `ls -l` format.

Comment: Thanks, it works, see: redd.it/g29zn, the last part in the OP, it works I just really want to understand the code.

Comment: Just saw your revision, now I'm completely clueless and confused. We haven't learn any of that in class.

Comment: You mean the sed parameters? ... I use a little used feature of sed that allows you to use ANY character as you expression separator ... whatever character you put after 's' IS the character that separates your search and replace expressions.  I use '@' instead of '/' because it can be really daunting looking at a lot of slashes when file paths are involved.

Comment: What do the double @'s do?, what exactly is s@^.*?, why is there a colon there?

Comment: LST is just a text var where I store the names of teh files that are different.  running something in $(  )  executes it ... and for sed part I am just stripping to the colon, to get the file names.  Note: the sed and bash would make for a very good reading material if you want to get good at this.  Alsoe ... dont forget to accept one of the answer given to you by all these nice people ;-)

Comment: I know that, I don't know shit about sed so all these characters look mega confusing to me, would be nice to know EXACTLY what they mean.

Comment: I cannot use sed or awk in this assignment, I've just been notified.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and dedication, at least I learnt a lot from reading the responses from this thread and studying their functionality, so I thank you for that sir ;)

Comment: Two final notes ... just because I decided to add this to my .bashrc and use it elsewhere, I noticed that **maybe** you would want to change the `ls -l` with `ls -ld` so that subdirs (if any) are not drilled-down into.  Also, initialize LST1 & LST2 (I typically declare them local with `local LST1', others ppl just do `unset LST1` ...)

Answer (score 2):

This almost works.  It mainly fails where there are files that are similar locations alphabetically between the two dirs.

```
sdiff -s <(ls -1 dir1) <(ls -1 dir2)
```

Comment: This works mighty well, aside from the fact that I can't have a message in between the output. I need to echo a message and then show the files different in a from b, then output another message and output the different files in a.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{print "some message"; for(i in a)if(a[i]<2){print i}}' <(ls -1 dir2) <(ls -1 dir1)
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ ls -1 dir1
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt

$ ls -1 dir2
file1.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt

$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{print "Files in dir1 but NOT in dir2"; for(i in a)if(a[i]<2){print i}}' <(ls -1 dir2) <(ls -1 dir1)
Files in dir1 but NOT in dir2
file5.txt
file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use diff for comparing:

```
diff <(ls -1 dir1) <(ls -1 dir2) | awk '{if ($1==">") print "in dir 2: "$2; if($1=="<") print "in dir 1: "$2;}'
```

You could also analyze it with read:

```
diff <(ls -1 $dir1) <(ls -1 $dir2) | while read status filename
do
  [ "$status" == "<" ] && echo "in dir 1: $(ls -l $dir1/$filename)"
  [ "$status" == ">" ] && echo "in dir 2: $(ls -l $dir2/$filename)"
done
```

Comment: That seems to work, though I don't know how to get it into ls -la format.

Answer (score 1):

The basic recipe of what you want to do, is already done using the [`diff`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) utility available on unix-like systems, or using cygwin or GnuWin on Windows.  You should exploit this fact.

If I have directory `a` and `b` with the following contents:

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ ls -R
.:
a  b

./a:
d  e  f  x  y  z

./b:
i  j  k  x  y  z
```

The `x`, `y`, and `z` are exactly the same in each directory.

I can achieve what you want using the `diff` command like this:

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ diff a b
Only in a: d
Only in a: e
Only in a: f
Only in b: i
Only in b: j
Only in b: k
```

If I add a new file to each directory (named `new`), which are different, I get the following:

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ diff a b
Only in a: d
Only in a: e
Only in a: f
Only in b: i
Only in b: j
Only in b: k
diff a/new b/new
1c1
< ezraa
---
> ezra
```

That is, it'll even tell you how, and where the differences in the files occur.  Of course, if you don't want or need this functionality, you're free to not use it.

You also get the following:

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ diff a c
diff: c: No such file or directory
```

---

With the heavy-lifting of this program done by diff, most of what you write will be parsing the output of this command, and then manipulating or outputting it as you see fit.

One of [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) or [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) might be of particular interest when you're doing this.

Comment: Yeah I got that but in OP the output is not listed as you have answered, thus your answer is not applicable, sorry!

Comment: I wasn't intending to write your program for you.  Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, I was in 'jerk-mode', was getting really frustrated with this program, thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Files that are in $dir1 but not $dir2"
for i in "$dir1/"*; do
    [[ -e "$dir2/$i" ]] || (cd "$dir1"; ls -l "$i")
done
echo
```

That's one half of it.

Replace `[[ ... ]]` by `[ ... ]` or `test ...` if not using Bash.