# Read lines from a file into a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to read a file containing lines into a Bash array.

I have tried the following so far:

## Attempt1

```
a=( $( cat /path/to/filename ) )
```

## Attempt2

```
index=0
while read line ; do
    MYARRAY[$index]="$line"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < /path/to/filename
```

Both attempts only return a one element array containing the first line of the file. What am I doing wrong?

**I am running bash 4.1.5**

Comment: You don't need to maintain an index with your `while` loop. You can append to an array like this: `myarray+=($line)`. If you need to increment an integer, you can do `(( index++ ))` or `(( index += 1 ))`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson or `let index++`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `((index++))` has a return value, which will likely terminate the script if run in `set -e` mode. The same applies to `let index++`. Using `A=$((A+1))` is safe.

Comment: @ceving: You should never use [`set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) it's a useless relic. Use proper error handling.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I like it, because it is efficient and because of that very useful. `set -eu` is my standard prelude.

Comment: Actually "Attempt 2" works (with bash 4.3), provided you set `MYARRAY=()` before. Just add `printf '. %q .\n' "${MYARRAY[@]}"` at the end and you will see this.  The problem probably was looking at `echo "$MYARRAY"` instead of `echo "${MYARRAY[@]}"`.  Also note: `read -r line` probably is better as it does no ` \ ` interpolation.  Perhaps consider `IFS='' read -r line` to read in leading and trailing spaces, too.

Comment: Strangely using your first Attempt I also got an array that only contains the first element when I tried to `echo` it. But I found that using the indexing such as `echo ${mylist[0]}` and `echo ${mylist[1]}` gives me different outputs.

Comment: Make sure set the Internal File Separator (IFS)  variable to  $'\n' so that it does not put each word into a new array entry.

    OLDIFS=${IFS}
    IFS=$'\n'
    declare -a  ARR
    ARR=( $(cat  "file.txt") )

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Latest revision based on comment from [BinaryZebra's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/bash-read-lines-in-file-into-an-array/11393884?noredirect=1#comment56571512_11393884)
and [tested here](https://gist.github.com/nhed/d36ea500986d8fb6211c).  The addition of `command eval` allows for the expression to be kept in the present execution environment while the expressions before are only held for the duration of the eval.

Use $IFS that has no spaces\tabs, just newlines/CR

```
$ IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'XYZ=($(cat /etc/passwd))'
$ echo "${XYZ[5]}"
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
```

Also note that you may be setting the array just fine but reading it wrong - be sure to use both double-quotes `""` and braces `{}` as in the example above

---

**Edit:**

Please note the many warnings about my answer in comments about possible glob expansion, specifically [gniourf-gniourf's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/bash-read-lines-in-file-into-an-array/11393884?noredirect=1#comment35615660_11393884) about my prior attempts to work around

With all those warnings in mind I'm still leaving this answer here  (yes, bash 4 has been out for many years but I recall that some macs only 2/3 years old have pre-4 as default shell)

**Other notes:**

Can also follow drizzt's suggestion below and replace a forked subshell+cat with

```
$(</etc/passwd)
```

The other option I sometimes use is just set IFS into XIFS, then restore after.  See also [Sorpigal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11394045/652904) which does not need to bother with this

Comment: Why set `IFS` to carriage return and line feed? `\r` will not appear in files with proper line endings, which will certainly include `passwd`.

Comment: The IFS tells bash how to parse text, it defines the set of characters that break up tokens in the parsing process.  By default it includes whitespaces (space & tab) as well as newline/CR - so my code above removes them just for the current parse - so that it is one line per array index (thats what I thought you were looking for)

Comment: @Sorpigal /etc/passwd is just an example, I dont know what file he is parsing, he could be on cygwin for all I know, pulling in files from anywhere on the system ... I would not want strays in there

Comment: @nhed: Thanks, I looked up IFS in the mean time. Yes, your explanation is how I am trying to implement it. However, when I subst /etc/password for my file. The array variable **XYZ** still contains only the first line in the file.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli  Can you show how you test your output?

Comment: @nhed: I simply type `echo $array` at the command line (where array is the array read into). I am expecting to see `a b c d e` if the file read in contains the lines 'a','b','c','d','e' with each line separated by a new line.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Please note the end of my post (2nd or 3rd edit :) )  - you have to double-quote and use braces, if you want all lines - you would `echo "${XYZ[@]}"`

Comment: `echo "${XYZ[@]}"` will print all elements as a single line; to get each element on a separate line use `printf "%s\n" "${XYZ[@]}"`.

Comment: why use useless fork? Just use $(</etc/passwd)

Comment: @drizzt Agree, but the OP asked about parsing the output so I'd rather  answer with minimal changes to his attempts if it works, but I'll add an suggestion in the answer

Comment: Please note that this is not a good general method! For example, if a file contains a `*`, this will go through filename expansions! Try it yourself: `echo '*' > file; cat file; IFS=$'\r\n'; a=( $(cat file) ); echo "${a[@]}"` Surprise!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf one set of double quotes solves that, doesn't it? `echo -e '*\nhi\n*' > file; IFS=$'\r\n' a=( "$(cat file)" ); echo "${a[@]}"`, BTW you had an extra `;` after IFS

Comment: @nhed no, because now you have an array with only one field! not an array the fields of which are the lines of `file`. Check with `declare -p a`. And btw, the `;` after `IFS` is optional (same effect with or without it).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf hmm I thought I tested that, but I'll double check

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf how about `echo -e '*\nhi\n*\n?' > file; GLOBIGNORE='*' IFS=$'\r\n' a=($(cat file)); echo "${a[@]}"`

Comment: Your method is now much longer that Sorpigal's or chepner's, much less natural, looks like a really dirty hack, globally sets `IFS` and `GLOBIGNORE` (I definitely don't want `GLOBIGNORE` or `set -f` in my script since my scripts are mainly here for file stuff and I rely a lot on globbing), and might still break in some obscure cases (actually, your method silently discards empty lines). Moreover this is slower than `mapfile`. Please just don't do that!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf globally?  no it does not!  These are only set for the duration of the array assignment (no `;`!) Just as IFS in Sorpigal's!  So the globbing is only disabled for the read.  As I mentioned to @drizzt above - I'd rather answer with minimal changes to the OP attempts.  As for chepner's solution, its not portable, requires a current version of bash which even the default /bin/bash on a relatively modern MacOS is still not supported

Comment: No you're wrong. `a=b c=d` is _equivalent_ to `a=b; c=d`. Please try it. That's just the way it is in Bash. Bash 4 was released in 2009 IIRC. We're now in 2014. If you don't have access to Bash 4, use Sorgipal's solution. BTW, in Sorgipal's solution `IFS` is _not_ globally set. And chepner's solution is just the way to do it in bash ≥4.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf compare `a=b c=d date; echo $c` (result is just the date), then compare to `a=b; c=d; date; echo $c` (result is date plus "d").   IFS is not set globally neither mine or sorpigals answer, only in your comment with the `;`!

Comment: Please try what you say: in a new clean environment: `IFS=lol GLOBIGNORE='*' XYZ=($(cat /etc/passwd))` and then `echo "$IFS"` (with the quotes!). Do you still say that you're not globally setting `IFS`? I can't explain to you in a comment why this sets the `IFS` but not Sorpigal's answer; it's just the way it is.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes you are correct.  I was testing `echo ${IFS}` vs `echo "${IFS}"`.  That difference I can't explain.  I can explain why IFS is set globally in my example, because the line just has assignments, and not assignments that precede a command, i'll update my answer

Comment: That's how variable assignment has worked in bash for the 25 years I've been using it.  "X=a Y=b" sets the variables for the shell.  "X=a Y=b executable" sets the variables only for the fork and exec environment of that one execution.  The ":;" in the given answer is counter-productive and pollutes the shell.

Comment: Why not update the "answer" given with the suggested fixes and optimizations: 

 IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' XYZ=($(< /etc/passwd))

Comment: Correction:  Can't combine the exec-only assignments with the $(<...) usage because that command has no executable.  Efficient work-around is to run the "true" executable:  IFS=$'\r\n' XYZ=($(< /etc/passwd)) true

Comment: APOLOGIES (with this thing let me edit my comments for 10 minutes instead of 5).  Correction:  The exec-only assignment won't work for this use case because the goal of assigning XYZ would not persist.  Have to set IFS then restore it afterward.

Comment: @Blaine Sure you can't edit, but I think you can delete your own comments - and then resubmit one cohesive one.  In practice I **usually** just set IFS before, then reset it after just to make my scripts less obscure (for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5279465/652904)

Comment: The current answer with `:;` is broken -- the variables `IFS` and `GLOBIGNORE` are only set while executing the `:` (`true`) command.  Is there any way to set `IFS` and `GLOBIGNORE` temporarily but still allow `XYZ` to persist?

Comment: For instance, if you try `IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' :; XYZ=($(echo '*'))` you should find that the `GLOBIGNORE` variable was set only for the evaluation of `:` (`true`) and not for the next command which assigns `XYZ`.  (I am using `4.1.17(9)-release` but that should not matter.)

Comment: @Hugues you are right, I had not used my original test cases when testing for my response, i.e. did not have wildcards

Comment: Assignments alone are set for *this* shell. Assignments for commands vary. If the command is external, the assignments are for that command environment only: `unset a b c d; a=b c=d bash -c 'echo "|$c|"'; echo "<$c>"`. But [for **special built-ins**, POSIX requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) (Variable assignments specified with special built-in utilities remain in effect after the built-in completes) that the value is set for **this** shell: `sh -c 'unset a b c d; a=b c=d  export f=g ; echo "<$a::$c::$f>"'` outputs `<b::d::g>`.

Comment: It is possible to set variables for only one command with `a=b c=d command eval 'f=g'; echo "<$a::$c::$f>"`. In such case vars `a` and `b` are set for the environment of the command `command`, but discarded after that. I'll edit the answer to include this solution.

Comment: In case the edit is rejected, what I added was `Placing variables in the environment of the split is done with command eval:

IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval 'XYZ=($(cat /etc/passwd))'` as the first two lines. Feel free to edit as this is your answer anyway. nJoy!

Comment: Thanks @BinaryZebra ...

Comment: What a solution .. finally.  Reading it hurts me somehow, however I was not able to spot any flaw in it like bad sideffects etc.  It even returns the error code in case the file is unreadable, so works with `set -e`.  And `command eval` wow, what a find!  I'd rather suggest `readarray` but for pre-4.0 `bash` this is really a way to do it.  (Note that it needs `bash` due to `GLOBIGNORE`)

Comment: @nhed How can I use this with `/bin/bash -c '$command'` ? it is required single quotoes of entire command. I am planning to use this in Exec parameter in systemctl service file ?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam your'e not giving me alot to go on but (A) I would not go crazy in `systemd` service files but rather write a script that you would be able to independently test and then invoke from the service file.  Also (B) my answer is kinda dated and now with bash 4 being so prevalent I usually try to stick to `readarray`/`mapfile` based solutions.

Comment: @nhed Ok, forget systemd. Can you give example how `IFS=$'\r\n'` can be done within /bin/bash -c ?  For example `/bin/bash -c 'IFS=$'\r\n' command eval  'XYZ=($(cat /etc/passwd))''` doesn't work. Just run in the terminal.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam in the above is quoting.  It gets hairy - I would still recomend not to do heavy lifting in a `bash -c` contect but you also ignored my note that my answer is dated - utilizing a more modern syntax would be `/bin/bash -c 'readarray XYZ < /etc/passwd; echo "${XYZ[0]}"'`.  I'm not saying its not possible to properly work out all the quoting gotchas but its not worth my or your time and certainly out of scope of this question

Comment: @nhed Thanks. Yes I figured out how to do it. Your method also works. I did it `while IFS= read -r f;do echo $f;done< <(command)`. I needed bash -c on mac where I am using zsh. But you are right, that part is outside scope of this answer.

Answer (score 424):

[The `readarray` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray) (also spelled `mapfile`) was introduced in bash 4.0.

```
readarray -t a < /path/to/filename
```

Comment: I think you are right about being introduced in bash 4, this doesn't work in bash 3.2

Comment: When I made that comment, I may not have been sure if it was in 4.0, or 4.1, or 4.2. Anyway, the [bash release notes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) confirm it was added in 4.0.

Comment: Easy to see on my MacOS as `/bin/bash` is 3 and `env bash` is 4 ... so I test expressions on my shell and they work fine, add expressions to script; but the scripts have a shebang `#!/bin/bash` which causes readarray to fail :(

Comment: For what it's worth, the shebang is only used when you execute the script as `myscript`. You can use `env bash myscript` to run your script with the newer version.

Comment: using any output: `bkpIFS="$IFS";IFS=$'\n';readarray astr < <(echo -e "a b c\nd e\nf");IFS="$bkpIFS";` checking `for str in "${astr[@]}";do echo $str;done;`

Comment: `readarray` doesn't use `IFS`; it only populates the named array with one line per element, with no field splitting.

Comment: yes I just had a problem with it concerning NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS that has '\012' (\n) char on it, still testing...

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11394045/1422630) worked with  NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS! wonder if readarray could work too?

Comment: I would suggest adding `-t` to the answer to strip off the newline characters. Makes it easier to use the array (e.g. for string comparisons) and it is not often that you'll want to keep the newline anyway.

Comment: @AquariusPower `bash` 4.4 will add a `-d` flag to `readarray` to specify an alternate character to terminate each line of the input.

Comment: @morloch thank you, not realizing there is a newline, I wasted many minutes trying to figure out what was wrong with my input, as sed couldn't process the lines. What a horrible default.

Comment: A gotcha: Don't forget to use process substitution with you're trying to do with the output of a command. Otherwise it doesn't work. Example: `readarray my_array < <(command)`

Comment: To clarify @starbeamrainbowlabs 's comment: If you write the line like `command | readarray -t varname` , the `varname` will be empty because `readarray` was run in a subshell.

Answer (score 151):

The simplest way to read each line of a file into a `bash` array is this:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < /etc/passwd
```

Now just index in to the array `lines` to retrieve each line, e.g.

```
printf "line 1: %s\n" "${lines[0]}"
printf "line 5: %s\n" "${lines[4]}"

# all lines
echo "${lines[@]}"
```

Comment: All lines, one per line: `printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"`.

Comment: this worked with NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS that has '\012' (\n) char on it, thx! using any output: `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a astr < <(echo -e "a b c\nd e\nf");` checking: `for str in "${astr[@]}";do echo $str;done;`

Comment: This will discard blank lines in the file: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream

Comment: In this context, `read` returns `false`, so you cannot distinguish from correct funktion or error like read errors.  `readarray` is a better way to go.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `IFS=$'\n' ` is doing in this expression; it seems to work just as well on a Mac without it

Comment: @Magnus: It's making read split the input in to fields on newline. This will also happen if you omit it, but you will additionally split on the other default input field separator: space. If your file's lines may have spaces this will lead to different results. If your `bash` is new enough you should in any case use `mapfile -t lines < /etc/passwd` instead which is more efficient and just as safe.

Comment: If you have an older version of Bash that doesn't have `mapfile` or `readarray` (e.g. Mac's ancient default version Bash), then you have to use this method.  Since `read` returns `false` here, you could add `|| true` to the end of the command to avoid having your program exit here if you have error checking (`set -e`) enabled.

Answer (score 29):

One alternate way if file contains strings without spaces with 1string each line:

```
fileItemString=$(cat  filename |tr "\n" " ")

fileItemArray=($fileItemString)
```

Check:

Print whole Array:

```
${fileItemArray[*]}

Length=${#fileItemArray[@]}
```

Comment: **Beware!** This expands shell metacharacters, for example if `fileItemString='*'`.  Can only be used safely when globbing is turned off, which in turn renders the shell mosty useless.

Comment: This will treat every whitespace in the file as separator (not only `\n`). I.e. if Nth line in the file is "foo bar", the resulting array will contain separate `foo` and `bar` entries, not a single `foo bar` entry.

Answer (score 26):

Your first attempt was close.  Here is the simplistic approach using your idea.

```
file="somefileondisk"
lines=`cat $file`
for line in $lines; do
        echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: This was close but didn't answer the part about populating an array.

Comment: lines **is** the array and can be referenced as such.

Comment: No, `lines` is *not* an array here; it's just a string. Sure, you're splitting that string on whitespace to iterate over it (and also expanding any globs it contains), but that doesn't make it into an array.

Comment: **Beware!** This expands shell metacharacters, for example if `lines='*'`.

Comment: While not being direct answer to question, this snippet actually solves the problem I had when google led me to this page.

Comment: This will treat every whitespace in the file as separator (not only \n). I.e. if Nth line in the file is "foo bar", the resulting output will contain `foo` and `bar` as separate line, not a single `foo bar` line.

Comment: There's so many problems with this example, i don't understand how it got 24 votes. Where is the IFS variable? Where is the quotations around variables?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' read  -d '' -r -a inlines  < testinput
IFS=$'\n' read  -d '' -r -a  outlines < testoutput
counter=0
cat testinput | while read line; 
do
    echo "$((${inlines[$counter]}-${outlines[$counter]}))"
    counter=$(($counter+1))
done
# OR Do like this
counter=0
readarray a < testinput
readarray b < testoutput
cat testinput | while read myline; 
do
    echo value is: $((${a[$counter]}-${b[$counter]}))
    counter=$(($counter+1))
done
```

Comment: Stick to `readarray`, because `read` returns `false`, so first solution fails under `set -e`.   Also note, that `counter` is still `0` after the loop, because it is done in a subshell (due to pipe).

Comment: OSX does not have `readarray`

Comment: @cmcginty, ...because Apple is shipping a copy of bash that's almost old enough to get a driver's license, yes; for anyone who cares about bash, they really should be installing a newer one rather than using the OS-vendor-provided copy.

Comment: One issue here: `read -d'' -r` is exactly the same as `read -d -r`; the `-` in `-r` becomes the delimiter. That's incorrect; what it _should_ be is `read -d '' -r`; the space between the `-d` and the `''` is critical.

Comment: To test that, try reading sample input that contains dashes -- it'll be truncated at them.