# Extract file contents into array using Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

How to extract a file content into array in Bash line by line.
Each line is set to an element.

I've tried this:

```
declare -a array=(`cat "file name"`)
```

but it didn't work, it extracts the whole lines into `[0]` index element

Comment: Usually you won't need that. Can you tell why you want that anyway?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11393817

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a loop to read each line of your file and put it into the array

```
# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {
    array=() # Create array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < "$1"
}

getArray "file.txt"
```

How to use your array :

```
# Print the file (print each element of the array)
getArray "file.txt"
for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$e"
done
```

Comment: I don't know why OP wants that. But however, this syntactically correct

Answer (score 43):

For bash version 4, you can use:

```
readarray -t array < file.txt
```

Comment: This is the sensible and efficient way to proceed in modern bash. Note that `readarray` is synonym of `mapfile`.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland I liked it because you helped me :-) thanks a lot

Comment: also `readarray --help` is very poor. If you need to know more check `mapfile --help`. Since mapfile is a shell built-in `man mapfile` redirects into `man bash` which is a very big place.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (Bash):

```
OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'; array=($(<file)); IFS="$OIFS"
```

Copy `$IFS`, set `$IFS` to newline, slurp file into array and reset `$IFS` back again.

Comment: This is subject to pathname expansion (and will discard empty lines)—don't use.