# How to spilit with IFS

Tags: ifs

I would like to split a text file with IFS my text file looks like :

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

I want to read this file and get name by name here is my code :

```
names=$(</text.txt)
IFS='\n' read -a -r names_list <<< "$names"

for name in "${names_list[@]}"
do
    echo "$name"
done
```

it's always showing the first name and not the others, any solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash: Read lines in file into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/bash-read-lines-in-file-into-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about the output you are looking for but to go through a file using a loop, here is the syntax:

```
sylvainkalache@holbertonschool$ cat text.txt
name1
name2
name3
name4
sylvainkalache@holbertonschool$ while read name
> do
> echo "$name"
> done < /tmp/file
name1
name2
name3
name4
sylvainkalache@holbertonschool$
```

You actually do not need to change the `IFS` variable.