# assign each line as a new variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have a bash script that gives me the following output:

```
'string1': {'something': u'2.000', 'anotherthing': u'3.0000000'
'string2': {'something': u'1.000', 'anotherthing': u'1.85695664'
'string3': {'something': u'1.000', 'anotherthing': u'4.0000000'
'string4': {'something': '01.000', 'anotherthing': u'0.43448059'
```

I want to assign each line with a variable ( strinx) ....I`ve tried  awk '{print "var"NR"="$0}' , but it just creates a variable like this:

```
var1=string1': {'something': u'2.000', 'anotherthing': u'3.0000000'
var2='string2': {'something': u'1.000', 'anotherthing': u'1.85695664'
var3='string3': {'something': u'1.000', 'anotherthing': u'4.0000000'
var4='string4': {'something': '01.000', 'anotherthing': u'0.43448059'.
```

How can i get more than 1 variables? Thank you

Comment: use the right tool for the job.. https://github.com/stedolan/jq

Comment: Don't parse json with sed/awk use [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info).

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/read-lines-from-a-file-into-a-bash-array

Comment: What you are interested in is refered to as an `array`. You might want to store each line of your text file in an array (lets call it `var`) and then you can refere to each element as `var[1]`, `var[2]`, ... . The duplicates indicate how you can do this.