# parse mysql result line by line and convert every line to array - bash script

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash, shell

I'm using bash scripts and for some reasons I must only use bash and not the php or perl and etc.

I got some results from mysql with this code and saved them in a variable called `result`:

```
result=$(mysql -NB -u "$mysqlUser" -p"$mysqlPass" -D "$mysqlDb" -e "select * from sites" )
```

and this is the result:

```
1 news.bitcoin.com    NULL 840119 stopped 1509636516 1509636688 0 0 0 0
2 blog.blockchain.com NULL NULL   stopped NULL       0          0 0 0 0
```

now I want to parse this results line by line and convert each line to an array and access them for example in this way:

```
echo $results[0,0] # 1
echo $results[0,3] # 840119
echo $results[0,6] # 1509636688
echo $results[1,1] # blog.blockchain.com
echo $results[1,3] # NULL
echo $results[1,6] # 0
```

accourding to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468914/3539776) we can declare arrays through andices like multidimensional.

Would you please help me with this issue, or inform me of any other possible ways to walk  through this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: bash does not natively support multi dimensional arrays

Comment: @Inian yes I know. but you can declare arrays via andices like multidimensional. for example: `test[0,1,2]=blabla       test[0,1,3]=blabla2` and so on ... see this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468914/3539776](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468914/3539776)

Comment: So why couldn't you use it and solve your use case, what is stopping you?

Comment: @Inian I don't know how iterate result variable line by line and how merge this code with code of converting line to array !! Im noob yet

Comment: Look at how to use `while` to read input line per line.

Comment: Is that dataset going to always be small enough not to cause problems? are you sure there will never be embedded field separators? What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @PaulHodges I use `-NB` switch in `mysql` which prevent from any extra characters in  output result of `mysql` and that's while there is not any separetor in `mysql` result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally my issue solved in this way:

```
declare -A results
row=0
while read -r line; do
    if [[ -z "${line// }" ]]; then 
        continue
    fi        

    declare -a temp2=($line)


    for (( col=0; col<${#temp2[@]}; col++ ));
    do

       results[$row,$col]=${temp2[$col]}

    done

    results[cols]=$(( ${#temp2[@]}-1 ))

    ((row++))
done <<< "$result"
results[rows]=$row
```

and results:

```
echo "${results[rows]}" # 2 => array rows count
echo "${results[cols]}" # 10 => array cols count
echo "${results[0,0]}" # 1
echo "${results[0,3]}" # 840119
echo "${results[0,6]}" # 1509636688
echo "${results[1,1]}" # blog.blockchain.com
echo "${results[1,3]}" # NULL
echo "${results[1,6]}" # 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the paranoia that fields are going to get mismatched, you could try just walking through the data and assigning it by brute force to parallel arrays.

```
row=0
declare -a A B C D 
mysql -NB -u "$mysqlUser" -p"$mysqlPass" -D "$mysqlDb" -e "select * from sites" |
while read a b c d # ...
do (( row++ ))
   A[$row]="$a"
   B[$row]="$b"
   C[$row]="$c"
   D[$row]="$d"
done
```

Please use better names than a,b,c... but then, assuming field 2 is fqdn, you'd be able to say

```
echo ${FQDN[2]}
```

to quickly grab that field from that row. The whole table becomes immediately accessible...but one misformatted line is going to shoot you in the foot.

Comment: your solution works when number of mysql result lines are static. for example only 4 lines. but my result lines is variable not static.

Comment: `row` is dynamically incremented for however many lines there are. It does expect a consistent number of columns, but every line, however many, gets parsed to fields as it comes it. How is this only going to work on 4 lines?

Comment: sorry I was wrong. I tested your code. but when I did `echo`, didn't show anything to me . `echo ${A[0]}` and `echo ${A[1]}` and `echo ${B[0]}` and `echo ${A[1]}` all were empty

Comment: What's the output if you pipe that mysql command through a head?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your output to csv - check [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)
One (not nice) way is:

```
csv=`echo "${result}" | tr '\t' ','`
```

Then do the magic:

```
declare -A output 
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'lines=($(echo "${csv}"))'        
for (( i=0; i<${#lines[@]}; i++ ));
do
  IFS=$',' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'oneline=($(echo "${lines[$i]}"))'
  for (( j=0; j<${#oneline[@]}; j++ ));
  do
    output[$i,$j]=${oneline[$j]}
  done
done
```

And finally

```
echo "${output[0,0]}" # 1
echo "${output[0,3]}" # 840119
echo "${output[0,6]}" # 1509636688
echo "${output[1,1]}" # blog.blockchain.com
echo "${output[1,3]}" # NULL
echo "${output[1,6]}" # 0
```

Be aware of all double quotes and curly brackets.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393884/2235381 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22432604/2235381

Comment: I tested your solution. but all of `$output` blocks were empty and didn't show me any values

Comment: Sorry case mishmash. Try now

Comment: it didn't work again. value of `${output[0,0]}`  is `1 news.bitcoin.com    NULL 840119 stopped 1509636516 1509636688 0 0 0 0` and value of `${output[1,0]}` is `2 blog.blockchain.com NULL NULL   stopped NULL       0          0 0 0 0` and rest of array blocks are empty