# Find and replace in JSON files

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to scripting.

I have the below three files:

```
Availability.json
Source URLs.txt
Target URLs.txt
```

My requirement is I need to search for URLs present in Source URLs.txt and replace them with Target URLs.txt in Availability.json file.

How can we achieve this in shell scripting? We have some 50 URLs.

Content:
Availability.json

```
"drillDownUrl": "https://appdync-mex-cgn-2u.mex.group.net:8090/controller/#/location=METRIC_BROWSER&timeRange=last_30_minutes.BEFORE_NOW.-1.-1.180&application=1000&metrics=APPLICATION_COMPONENT.647.4743559",

         "label": null,
        "description": null,
        "drillDownUrl": "https://appdync-mex-cpo-7u.mex.group.net:8090/controller/#/location=METRIC_BROWSER&timeRange=last_30_minutes.BEFORE_NOW.-1.-1.180&application=1&metrics=APPLICATION_COMPONENT.647.474",
```

Source_URLs.txt

```
 https://appdync-mex-cgn-2u.mex.group.net:8090/controller/#/location=METRIC_BROWSER&timeRange=last_30_minutes.BEFORE_NOW.-1.-1.180&application=1000&metrics=APPLICATION_COMPONENT.647.4743559

https://appdync-mex-cpo-7u.mex.group.net:8090/controller/#/location=METRIC_BROWSER&timeRange=last_30_minutes.BEFORE_NOW.-1.-1.180&application=1&metrics=APPLICATION_COMPONENT.647.474
```

Target_URLs.txt:

```
https://www.apdyn.com/Application#=12
https://www.appdyn.com/Application#=123
```

Comment: You'll need to break the problem down a bit and show us also what's in some of those files.

Comment: In the json file we have some 50 URLs similar to 
http://appdyn.net/Application=12/components=12345....In Source_URLs.txt we have all 50 URLs which are present in json and in Target_URLs.txt we have URLs to be replaced...Need to replace all 50 URLs from Target_URLs file  injson file...hope it make sense...

Comment: You need to show a sample of your JSON and an example of the source and target URL. That link you pasted here doesn't work.

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash? Do you need it to work with just your shell, or are you aiming for wide compatibility? It is good to be specific here.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. We will be using bash  and no aim for other.

Answer (score 1):

Updated version - `readarray` used as suggested and separators in sed are now `|`. I used your filenames. Please remove blank line and leading space in your `Source_URLs.txt`

```
readarray -t SRC < Source_URLs.txt
echo "${SRC[1]}"

readarray -t TRGT < Target_URLs.txt
echo "${TRGT[1]}"

for (( i=0; i<${#SRC[@]}; i++ ));
do
  sed -i "s|${SRC[$i]}|${TRGT[$i]}|g" Availability.json
done
```

Note: Your `Availability.json` is not valid - last character is `,` there is duplicate key and there's no object - check it in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Add this line at the beginning of the script to get rid of the blank lines from  **Source_URLs.txt:** `sed -i "/^[[:space:]]*$/d" Source_URLs.txt`

Answer (score 0):

load your urls into arrays (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393884/2235381) According to your OS `IFS` may vary.

```
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'SRC=($(cat src.txt))'
echo "${SRC[0]}"

IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'TRGT=($(cat trgt.txt))'
echo "${TRGT[0]}"
```

backup your json and then iterate over array with `sed -i`, e.g.:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#SRC[@]}; i++ ));
do
  sed -i "s/${SRC[$i]}/${TRGT[$i]}/g" your.json
done
```

I know it's bit brute force, but for 50 lines ok. Suggest better solution if you have.

Comment: Thanks for the idea...I will give a try

Comment: Getting the below error, can you help?                                                                                   
    sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
    sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Updated my question with file content, please enlighten me

Comment: URLs have `/`s in them. You can't use `s/$foo/$bar/` when `$foo` and `$bar` have slashes. (This will also misbehave for any URL that uses characters that parse as regular expressions; for example, any `.` in a URL will be treated as a wildcard, matching any character).

Comment: ...and the `eval` usage here is major-security-bugs level unfortunate, and utterly unnecessary. `readarray -t src <src.txt` is a **much** safer way to read a file into an array one-entry-per-line. (See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for some background on the risks created by `eval`).

Comment: Thanks for the update...can you let me know how to use sed for URLs?