# Average value in CSV files bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm currently writing a bash script to find out a server's average memory usage per hour, that outputs to a .csv file. What will happen is, the script will run at every 10th min and after running six times in an hour, I'll have 6 different values for the hour in my .csv file and so.

What I'm trying to do is to use the script find out the average value for each hour.

```
#date(YYYYMMDDHHmm) total     used
201811270000        10        3
201811270010        10        4
201811270020        10        5
201811270030        10        9
201811270040        10        8
201811270050        10        2
201811270100        10        5
201811270110        10        1
201811270120        10        7
201811270130        10        6
201811270140        10        5
201811270150        10        2
201811270200        10        1
```

Based on the output above, does anyone know a way I can find the average of each hour? For example:

```
The average of hour 201811270000: 5.166666666666667
The average of hour 201811270100: 4.333333333333333
```

How do I go about this?

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes it is possible, do you have already any piece of code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Furthremore, you mention a CSV file which is a _Comma Separated File_. It seems your input is not a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Awkward,

```
awk '
  function calc() {
    if (count) print "The average of hour " date ": " (sum/count);
    count=0; sum=0; date=$1;
  }
  /^#/ {next}             # throw away comment lines
  $1~/00$/ {calc()}       # full hour, time to calculate/reset variables
  END {calc()}            # end of file, ditto
  {count+=1; sum+=$3;}    # update variables at each line
' < file.txt
```

Pure bash would be herculean, as you'd need to implement floating point arithmetic library first. :)

Comment: I've always hated `awk`, but you guys are making me appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "[tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)" to trim the line into smaller, space separated chunks, "[cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)" out the parts we need to calculate the average. In case the format gets more complex you can always enhance the `getFieldAtPosition` function.

I don't have a fullfledged bash here atm so I used an array to iterate over instead of reading from file input.
For a way to read a file line by line you can check out this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1177024

Short bash-only version:

```
    function average {
       local sum=$1
       local count=$2
       local floatingPointUnits=2

       # https://linux.die.net/man/1/dc
       echo "${floatingPointUnits}k" "$sum" "$count" /p | dc
    }

   function getFieldAtPosition {
        local line=$1
        local position=$2

        echo "$line"  | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f $position
    }

    function parseHourFromDate {
        local date=$1
        local positionOfHour=4+2+2
        local lengthOfHour=2

        echo ${date:positionOfHour:lengthOfHour}
    }

    lines=('201811270000        10        3      ' \
        '201810270020        7        2      ' \
        '201811270100        10        3      ' \
        '201810270140        22        2      ' \
        '201811271000        33        3      ' )

    sum=0
    count=0
    declare -A HOURS
    for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
        date=`getFieldAtPosition "$line" 1`
        number=`getFieldAtPosition "$line" 2`
        hour=`parseHourFromDate "$date"`

        # new hour, reset
        if [ "$hour" != "$previousHour" ]; then
           sum=0
           count=0
        fi

        sum=$((sum+number))
        count=$((count+1))

        # save average in associative array
        HOURS[$hour]=`average $sum $count`
        previousHour=$hour
    done


    # print results
    for key in "${!HOURS[@]}"; do
        echo "Average of $key: ${HOURS[$key]}"
    done
```

Comment: `dc`, `cut`, `tr` are not bash. When I said "bash-only", I meant bash builtins and nothing else. If you can use external programs, why not use _nicer_ external programs? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
> cat ivan.txt
201811270000        10        3
201811270010        10        4
201811270020        10        5
201811270030        10        9
201811270040        10        8
201811270050        10        2
201811270100        10        5
201811270110        10        1
201811270120        10        7
201811270130        10        6
201811270140        10        5
201811270150        10        2
201811270200        10        1
> perl -F'/\s+/'  -lane ' { $F[0]=~s/..$//g;push @{$datekv{$F[0]}},$F[2];} END { for my $x (sort keys %datekv){ $total=0;$z=0; foreach(@{$datekv{$x}}) {$total+=$_;$z++ } print $x,"\t",$total/$z }}' ivan.txt
2018112700      5.16666666666667
2018112701      4.33333333333333
2018112702      1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash and bc to calculate:

```
PROCESS_FILE="file.txt"
PROCESSED_DATE=""

while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^# ]]; then
                 continue;
        fi

        LINE_DATE=${line:0:10}
        if [[ $PROCESSED_DATE != *"$LINE_DATE"* ]]; then
                PROCESSED_DATE+=","+$LINE_DATE
                USED_LIST=$(grep $LINE_DATE $PROCESS_FILE | sed 's/  */,/g' | cut -d ',' -f3 | tr '\n' ' ')
                COUNT=0;
                SUM=0;
                for USED in $USED_LIST; do
                        COUNT=$(echo "$COUNT + 1" | bc -l);
                        SUM=$(echo "$SUM + $USED" | bc -l);
                done

                if [ $COUNT -ne 0 ]; then
                        AVG=$(echo "$SUM/$COUNT" | bc -l)
                fi
                echo "The average of hour $LINE_DATE: $AVG"
        fi

done < $PROCESS_FILE
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a short (a bit brute) way to do it in bash:

```
calc() {
awk "BEGIN { print "$*" }";
}

IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'memory=($(<'$1'))'
for (( i = 0; i < ${#memory[@]}; i++ )); do
echo "${memory[i]}" | awk '{print $1" "$3}' >> values.txt
total=$(awk '{ (Values += $2) } END { printf "%0.0f", Values }' values.txt)
length=$(awk '{print $2}' values.txt | wc -l)
echo "The average of hour $(awk '{print $1}' values.txt | tail -n1): $(calc ${total}/${length})"
done
rm values.txt
```

The result of the execution is the following:

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ ./processing.sh test.csv 
The average of hour 201811270000: 3
The average of hour 201811270010: 3.5
The average of hour 201811270020: 4
The average of hour 201811270030: 5.25
The average of hour 201811270040: 5.8
The average of hour 201811270050: 5.16667
The average of hour 201811270100: 5.14286
The average of hour 201811270110: 4.625
The average of hour 201811270120: 4.88889
The average of hour 201811270130: 5
The average of hour 201811270140: 5
The average of hour 201811270150: 4.75
The average of hour 201811270200: 4.46154
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$
```

You can later change the output to forward it to a file. 
There are more elegant ways of doing this for experienced bash users.

For Paul Hodges:

Awk is to point to the specific column in question as we don't know if that column has the same length as the rest of the file (**Still Applies**).

tr -d is necesarry as the value of the variable needs to be an integer and not a string (**Only at command line**):

This is a string:

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/ScriptsClientes/BashReports/Tools/TextProcessing$ cat values.txt | wc -l
13
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/ScriptsClientes/BashReports/Tools/TextProcessing$
```

This is an integer:

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/ScriptsClientes/BashReports/Tools/TextProcessing$ cat values.txt | wc -l | tr -d '\n'
13ivo@spain-nuc-03:
```

Addtionally just doing wc -l file returns the following(**Still applies**):

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/ScriptsClientes/BashReports/Tools/TextProcessing$ wc -l values.txt 
13 values.txt
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/ScriptsClientes/BashReports/Tools/TextProcessing$
```

Not at all suitable for the task at hand as it forces you to filter out the name of the file.

Please be sure before criticizing.

Comment: Why `tr` out newlines the parser strips anyway? [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) - `memory=$(<file)`. `awk` out a column just to count with `wc`? Use `wc -l file`. 5 `awk`s when 1 could have done all this...or none. If writing all-bash, try not to open subshells at all. Test whether components are necessary! Minimalism is your friend. Unrequired processes put more load on machines - might be why the OP needs to monitor memory, right? I know this sounds harsh, and I'm sincerely sorry. It's good to offer help, but make it a learning opportunity for all.

Comment: That said, bravo for submitting an answer! Please don't stop doing that. It puts you head and shoulders above the folk who never give back. Good job. Just make a point of always improving. ;)

Comment: @PaulHodges tr is to remove the \n at the end of a value... When you do wc -l you get a return line at the end:

Comment: @PaulHodges I have learned from the question I opened what you showed me regarding cat and avoid using repeating some commands... This is a slow process of improvement and it takes practice... Practice makes perfect...  Thanks for pointing out my mistakes but here you aren't right.

Comment: @PaulHodges Check the update on my answer for details...

Comment: @PaulHodges Regarding cat you are right! Didn't know $(<file) would work.
Took it straight from the following thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/read-lines-from-a-file-into-a-bash-array
And didn't read the comments on the answer...

Comment: @PaulHodges One last thing. He asked for a bash script, not an awk one ;)

Comment: Again, apologies if it feels like I'm picking on you. I just want to make sure people know `length=$( wc -l < x )` doesn't require another process to strip newlines. `awk '{print $2}' x` will print a line for every line of `x` whether ithat line has a `$2` or not. I'm really not picking on you, and it's obvious that you aren't a clueless neophyte, but the newline is stripped before the assignment anyway, and `13` in bash is a token, pretty much always a string unless used in an integer context. If I hit a nerve, again, I'm sorry.

Comment: @PaulHodges wc -l generates a new line. Please look at the answer again and compare when tr-d is present and when it is not. The definition would work either way. In one case you are defining an integer, in the other a string.
Don't worry about criticizing, I already have "striping useless cat" from all my scripts on my "to do" list thanks to you. I got on here to learn as I don't get feedback on the code I do at work.

Comment: Try this: `length=$( wc -l < x ); echo "[$x]"` The newline already gets stripped during the assignment. I understand what you are doing, but newlines are tokenizing characters unless explicitly protected. You don't have to do it for the assignment.

Comment: @PaulHodges for this assignment not, but it is always better to work with the proper data type in case you need to do comparisons...

Comment: bash [doesn't have data types](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html), though you could `declare -i length=$( wc -l < x )` to be sure.

Comment: @PaulHodges Numeric vs String comparissons: 
https://www.linuxtechi.com/compare-numbers-strings-files-in-bash-script/
Notice a difference?

Comment: @PaulHodges From tldp: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#EX13 
Look at example Example 7-5.

"#  Here "a" and "b" can be treated either as integers or strings.
#  There is some blurring between the arithmetic and string comparisons,
#+ since Bash variables are not strongly typed.

#  Bash permits integer operations and comparisons on variables
#+ whose value consists of all-integer characters.
#  Caution advised, however."

Comment: These prove my point. The values are the same, the operators are different. Can you show me an example where the `tr` is required?

Comment: @PaulHodges It proofs my point they are not. Even in the manual of tldp they are referring to them differently:
13 - number(integer) 13\n - string
You could not use any of the greater than, less than operators (-gt, -lt) that appear in the manual with a string.

Comment: But the newline *would never have been there*. That's my point. You are calling `tr` in a situation that only applies from the command line - never in an assignment. Please test it.

Comment: @PaulHodges Aha... I learned from Pandora FMS monitoring system to always put tr -d for the trailing \n and do things first in the command line. Another thing to put on my "to do" list... Thanks!!

Comment: It's an awesome tool to have in the box, and you *should* always test it on the command line first! :D