# How do I convert the a table of data into list entires

Tags: shell

Let's say below is a table data is stored in a variable called "data"

```
1 apple 50 Mary
2 banana 40 Lily
3 orange 34 Jack

# 

for i in ${data}
do
  echo $i

done


# Expected Output
1 apple 50 Mary
2 banana 40 Lily
3 orange 34 Jack
```

How do I convert the above table of data into three entires so that i can iterate over it using a for-loop and print that single entry in exact same format.

Any suggestion.

Comment: What shell are you using? Is ``table data`` a file? And why didn't you store your ``table data`` in an array? Check out this link [Read lines from a file into a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/read-lines-from-a-file-into-a-bash-array)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Darkman for this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/read-lines-from-a-file-into-a-bash-array" link, it helps in my cause.

```
# This below line help
# IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*'

data="1 apple 50 Mary
2 banana 40 Lily
3 orange 34 Jack"

IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*'
for i in ${data}
do
  echo $i
  echo "test" 
done

# Resulted Output
1 apple 50 Mary
test
2 banana 40 Lily
test
3 orange 34 Jack
test
```