# Awk to extract platformio.ini environments to a bash array

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to extract all the environments defined in a platformio.ini file so I can loop through them and perform some action before building. The file looks like:

```
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File

[env]
extra_scripts = pre:./somescript.py

[env:FirstEnvironment]
platform = atmelavr
board = nanoatmega328
framework = arduino

[env:SecondEnvironment]
platform = atmelavr
board = nanoatmega328
framework = arduino
```

I can manually do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/924827)

```
declare -a environments=(
"FirstEnvironment" 
"SecondEnvironment"
)
for i in "${environments[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

But I now want to extract the information from the file. I've tried

```
awk '/\[env:.*\]/{print $0 }' platformio.ini
```

And it lists the environments but how can I create an array with that info?
I've also seen [readarray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395181/924827) so maybe I could create an array with all the lines and then only execute if there is a match in a condition? I need to loop this twice so it would be cleaner to create the array only with the info I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash + awk` you can do this:

```sh
readarray -t environments < <(
   awk -F 'env:' 'NF==2 {sub(/\]$/, ""); print $2}' file)

# check content of array
declare -p environments

declare -a environments=([0]="FirstEnvironment" [1]="SecondEnvironment")
```

Or else:

```sh
for i in "${environments[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
readarray -t environments < <(
   awk -v RS='(^|\n)\\[env:[^]]*\\](\n|$)' 'RT{gsub(/^\n|\n$|\n\[env:|\]\n/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file)

# Get/print contents of array name environments here:
declare -p environments


##Output of printing array's elements will be:
declare -a environments=([0]="FirstEnvironment" [1]="SecondEnvironment")
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, running `awk` command(where setting `RS` to `(^|\n)\\[env:[^]]*\\](\n|$)` regex and in main block of program removing all thing and getting only needed/required output part from `gsub` in `RT` between `[env:` to till `]` and its reading input from Input_file) and sending its output to `readarray` command to create bash array named `environments`. Then using `declare -p` command printing values of array along with its index items to show array's structure.