# Bash how to split a string on new line that has lines with spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

Can anyone explain what is going on here. I recently added shellcheck to my scripting regime, but some of the recommendations have broken what I was doing previously. For example I have a script that takes in an issue id and comment to post to it. I want to parse out @(Name) from it to add mentions to the comment, but looping over new lines and words is now broken with some updates shellcheck recommended.

```bash
comment-issue --issue-id [id] --comment "This is a comment
That spans multiple lines
and allows me to mention @(Coworker Name)"
```

The script is as follows (omitting parts not dealing with the splitting and processing of the comment)

```bash
...
# 1
IFS=$'\n' comment_lines=($comment)
# 2
for comment_line in "${comment_lines[@]}"; do

    # 3
    IFS=' ' read -r -a comment_line_words <<< "$comment_line"
    # 4
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#comment_line_words[@]}; i++)); do

        # Do processing to look for @, build paragraphs, etc.

    done
done

...
```

Parts 3 and 4 of this work perfectly. However parts 1 and 2 do not. Here's a few things that confuse me.

Part 1 is what is the issue now. shellcheck complains that I need to quote the `$comment` or split using `mapfile` or `read -a`. So I tried to add the quotes around the `$comment` to result in `IFS=$'\n' comment_lines=("$comment")` but now it only loops over the first line with the above code. Why does adding the quotes stop IFS from performing the split?

Secondly I decided ok let's take a look into read -a and see if I can satisfy it that way. So I stumbled upon the command `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a comment_lines <<< $comment` which works but shellcheck also tells me to quote the `$comment` in this case, but once I do once again the array then only loops over the first line. I assume the explanation from above is the same for this one?

Is the solution to this to just tell shellcheck that it's ok not to quote in this case (e.g. add an ignore to that line specifically)? or is there something else I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11393817/1765658) address your need?

Comment: Or [mabe this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash/4651495?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C265.7309#4651495) or even [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C194.9081)

Comment: Bash and zsh are two separate shells. Tag one, or the other; not both at the same time.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a comment_lines < <(printf '%s\n' "$comment" && printf '\0')`, btw, works as-intended. The `-d` is critical, though, to make `$'\n'` stop being the **record** separator as well as the **field** separator; because `read` stops after one record -- so if the two separators are the same, it'll only ever read exactly one field.

Comment: Why is this tagged _zsh_, when you are using bash? Correct tagging is important here, in particular since word splitting is done differently in zsh and bash, and the `read` command is also different between them.

Comment: Sorry for the miss tagging. I use ZSH as my terminal but write the scripts with bash, so I just got confused as to which was required.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does adding the quotes stop IFS from performing the split?

**`IFS` does not itself perform word splitting**.  It just tells the shell *how* to perform word splitting (on which delimiters) when word splitting is, in fact, done.  If you expand a variable inside double quotes, *e.g.* `"$comment"`, then the expansion is not subject to word splitting no matter what value `IFS` has.

> Secondly I decided ok let's take a look into read -a and see if I can satisfy it that way. So I stumbled upon the command `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a comment_lines <<< $comment` which works

That doesn't work for me in Bash 4.4.20, at least not as I think you want.  Nor would I expect it to do.  Array `comment_line` receives only a single element, containing the first line of the comment.  That's because each `read` execution reads only one line.  The line that is read is subject to word splitting, which uses `IFS`, so setting that to just a newline ensures that the contents of that line are not split into separate array elements.

> but shellcheck also tells me to quote the $comment in this case, but once I do once again the array then only loops over the first line. I assume the explanation from above is the same for this one?

I don't accept that you get what you want without quoting the expansion of `comment`, but you do not get what you want when you do quote that expansion.  Failing to quote `$comment` could easily end up with it being interpreted as multiple words.  Only the first will then be redirected into your `read` command.  On the other hand, quoting it will ensure that the whole contents of `$comment` is redirected into `read` -- not less than in the other case, but possibly more, starting with the same content.

**Shellcheck can't be sure exactly what you want to achieve, so you should not interpret its suggestions as being equally appropriate alternatives**.  Often, they are instead alternatives serving *different* possible objectives.  It is incumbent on you to understand what each one does, and select the one that does what you want.

In this case, `read` is the wrong tool for your line-splitting job.    The best match is instead `mapfile`.  Documentation excerpt:

> Read lines from the standard input into the indexed array variable

So, no need to mess with `IFS` for that, just ...

```
mapfile -t comment_lines <<< "$comment"
```

That gets you `comment_lines` as an array with one element for each line of the multi-line value of `comment` (without trailing newlines).

With that in place, your iteration at (#2) will behave as it appears you want (one iteration per comment line).

Additionally, **you should be careful about manipulating `IFS`**.  You can easily produce unwanted effects by changing it, so if ever you do change it then you would be wise to be sure to change it back as soon as possible.  Or, better, perform the change in a limited scope, such as with a `local` variable inside a shell function.  In what I see of your script, though, there does not appear to be any need to manipulate `IFS` at all.  I suspect that some of your observations were muddled by exactly this problem.

***Addendum***

If you must do the job with `read` then you could *use* the fact that it reads only one line per call:

```bash
comment_lines=()
while read -r; do
    comment_lines+=("$REPLY")
done <<<"$comment"
```

To do it with a single `read` command, you need to specify a logical line terminator that does not appear in your lines, maybe

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d $'\0' -a comment_lines
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, very well explained and helpful to my knowledge. A few follow ups. 1. I am using Bash < 4.0 so I don't have the mapfile/readarray available. I'd likely keep it that way as most of the scripts I right I'm using on MacOS which ships with 3.0 < 4.0 as the version. 2. To my understanding and maybe this is wrong but since I'm using the IFS on the same line It doesn't propagate past that line? I think I found that said somewhere as I know that editing it is not a good idea, but was what I had found so far for bash 3.0 to split strings.

Comment: Further to point 1. I'd need to add a line at the top of the script if I were to enforce people needing Bash 4.0 or higher to make sure that they are on that version. I already have similar checks for dependencies that I use in the scripts. (e.g. `jq)` is that a recommended thing to do or is there another way to enforce the required bash version? `type jq >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "jq is a required dependency (brew install jq). Aborting."; show-help; return; }`

Comment: @DMCApps, regarding (1), I have added some comments about doing the job with `read`.

Comment: @DMCApps,  regarding (2), your understanding seems a bit off, and that also brings up an issue with your original code that I did not previously highlight.  First, if you prepend variable assignments to a *simple command* then those are reflected in the environment of that command, but not in the host shell.  I guess that's what you're thinking of.  But that's not what you have at, for example, line `#1` in your original code.  Other than the variable assignments, there is only an empty command there, so the variables are set in the host shell. [...]

Comment: [...] Also, each command is expanded in full before it is parsed.  That means that a variable assignment in a given command cannot affect the expansion of that command itself -- it isn't even recognized *as* a variable assignment until after the command is expanded.  That means that in `IFS=$'\n' comment_lines=($comment)`, not only (i) the two variable assignments both apply to the host shell, but also (ii) the modification of `IFS` does not affect the interpretation of the assignment to `comment_lines`.

Comment: And please note that I am distinguishing between *commands* and *lines*.  There is a correlation between these in that newlines serve as command terminators in many common contexts, but a single line can contain multiple commands, and a single command can span multiple lines.